# How would one compress this if statement in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am currently creating a calculator in Python, and I have come across a small problem: I have 28 conditions in my if-else statement:

```
if operation0 == "+" and operation1 == "+" and operation2 == "+": # First operation is addition
    print(number0 + number1 + number2 + number3)
elif operation0 == "+" and operation1 == "+" and operation2 == "*":
    print(number0 + number1 + number2 * number3)
elif operation0 == "+" and operation1 == "+" and operation2 == "^":
    print(number0 + number1 + number2 ** number3)
elif operation0 == "+" and operation1 == "*" and operation2 == "+":
    print(number0 + number1 * number2 + number3)
elif operation0 == "+" and operation1 == "*" and operation2 == "*":
    print(number0 + number1 * number2 * number3)
elif operation0 == "+" and operation1 == "*" and operation2 == "^":
    print(number0 + number1 * number2 ** number3)
elif operation0 == "+" and operation1 == "^" and operation2 == "+":
    print(number0 + number1 ** number2 + number3)
elif operation0 == "+" and operation1 == "^" and operation2 == "*":
    print(number0 + number1 ** number2 * number3)
elif operation0 == "+" and operation1 == "^" and operation2 == "^":
    print(number0 + number1 ** number2 ** number3)
elif operation0 == "*" and operation1 == "+" and operation2 == "+": # First operation is multiplication
    print(number0 * number1 + number2 + number3)
elif operation0 == "*" and operation1 == "+" and operation2 == "*":
    print(number0 * number1 + number2 * number3)
elif operation0 == "*" and operation1 == "+" and operation2 == "^":
    print(number0 * number1 + number2 ** number3)
elif operation0 == "*" and operation1 == "*" and operation2 == "+":
    print(number0 * number1 * number2 + number3)
elif operation0 == "*" and operation1 == "*" and operation2 == "*":
    print(number0 * number1 * number2 * number3)
elif operation0 == "*" and operation1 == "*" and operation2 == "^":
    print(number0 * number1 * number2 ** number3)
elif operation0 == "*" and operation1 == "^" and operation2 == "+":
    print(number0 * number1 ** number2 + number3)
elif operation0 == "*" and operation1 == "^" and operation2 == "*":
    print(number0 * number1 ** number2 * number3)
elif operation0 == "*" and operation1 == "^" and operation2 == "^":
    print(number0 * number1 ** number2 ** number3)
elif operation0 == "^" and operation1 == "+" and operation2 == "+": # First operation is exponentiation
    print(number0 ** number1 + number2 + number3)
elif operation0 == "^" and operation1 == "+" and operation2 == "*":
    print(number0 ** number1 + number2 * number3)
elif operation0 == "^" and operation1 == "+" and operation2 == "^":
    print(number0 ** number1 + number2 ** number3)
elif operation0 == "^" and operation1 == "*" and operation2 == "+":
    print(number0 ** number1 * number2 + number3)
elif operation0 == "^" and operation1 == "*" and operation2 == "*":
    print(number0 ** number1 * number2 * number3)
elif operation0 == "^" and operation1 == "*" and operation2 == "^":
    print(number0 ** number1 * number2 ** number3)
elif operation0 == "^" and operation1 == "^" and operation2 == "+":
    print(number0 ** number1 ** number2 + number3)
elif operation0 == "^" and operation1 == "^" and operation2 == "*":
    print(number0 ** number1 ** number2 * number3)
elif operation0 == "^" and operation1 == "^" and operation2 == "^":
    print(number0 ** number1 ** number2 ** number3)
else:
    print("Error")
```

Nothing I tried worked, and I could find nothing on this website to help me compress the code. This many repeating elifs is unreasonable, and any amount of reduction would be appreciated.

Comment: What I think would be best is an implementation of the [shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Answer (score 3):

**DISCLAIMER:** The solution may use various concepts that are not relevant enough to explain here.

To get precedence, you will have to properly parse the input. There are several methods to do this; one common one is Dijkstra's [shunting yard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm?oldformat=true) algorithm.
Since this is just an example, we will be forgoing good practice (error handling, classes) for more concise code.

Firstly, we need to list out the precedences. A higher precedence means an operator has higher priority, so it gets executed earlier.

```py
precedences = {
    '^': 3,
    '*': 2, '/': 2,
    '+': 1, '-': 1
}
```

Then, we need to associate actions with each operator. To do this we can use the functions in the `operator` module:

```py
from operator import pow, truediv, mul, add, sub
do = {
    '^': pow,
    '*': mul, '/': truediv,
    '+': add, '-': sub
}
```

Finally, we need to implement the logic that decides when to evaluate an expression. First, we have one more number than operation, so we put that onto a stack:

```py
def shunt(numbers, operations):
    stack = [numbers.pop(0)]
    operators = []
```

Then, we handle each operator-number pair.

```py
    while len(numbers):
        operator = operations.pop(0)
        precedence = precedences[operator]
```

An operation is evaluated (using the `do` dictionary) when it has a higher precedence (is executed earlier) than the current operation. We remove the left and right operands from the stack, and lookup the appropriate function from `do` to evaluate the result:

```py
        while operators and precedences[operators[-1]] >= precedence:
            [left, right], stack[-2:] = stack[-2:], []
            stack.append(do[operators.pop()](left, right))
```

We then append the current operator and number to the stacks:

```py
        operators.append(operator)
        stack.append(numbers.pop(0))
```

After all numbers and operators have been used up, we evaluate the rest of the operators until only a single number is left, and return that:

```py
    while len(stack) > 1:
        [left, right], stack[-2:] = stack[-2:], []
        stack.append(do[operators.pop()](left, right))
    return stack[0]
```

Putting it all together ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVPbbtswDH22voLzHmInStbEGIYFSH/EcAEnUmphtiRI8roL9u0ZKdu1U/SlT5J4OTw8pOzv0Bhd3G5XZzowVro6GAeqs8YFsOaFQ3C9FOonh65vOdRCcPD9mTHr5EUKqS/Swwn@smT1tDpCwfGyxsuBw@pLPNGwwcseDVs62T/GhFnkUJkxK9aIeVPZMTvWjflUnBDkFXzT65DpvjtL5/lIXxnt8yNLfKgvP7BKOfp31tjsIa9YMrVJvEt8vzSqldBKPUFR@msUBs3AIwi65/YxYKFFOeUhcPIZBuzQSCdBeaj1LHJo6gBnpYWHoJ6bIB2K3TsNKoDSwVCw/IXQ3mNpRBuwZva1Fu9W9uV2X1XwuORFHSVlK6@Bg6NqFY6RFCq3h2OFLcwPHkVJBgF3tbVSi0yYGT6KkFfZAi3PF4r5KWkykPMO7X4k@XIEMS6HR9gT5Q8x/ihhJ6PcA85DdWuVpmEqbfuQ5WzkRMZPJ0hT5DPypr1Zd7XNcEw8Ruy8bVXIUkjztxs2wi0iWHLF8SMWrSz64Y@yb7fYjFtonRpWnBwcsLPTAPHqoCwa@NKJO9O3gTR674cQ9gSQnlJUJIaj7V6BWwEH/K5r2LBvUEDBNrBmB/gK39kT3th/)):

```py
from operator import pow, truediv, mul, add, sub

precedences = {
    '^': 3,
    '*': 2, '/': 2,
    '+': 1, '-': 1
}

do = {
    '^': pow,
    '*': mul, '/': truediv,
    '+': add, '-': sub
}

def shunt(numbers, operations):
    stack = [numbers.pop(0)]
    operators = []
    while len(numbers):
        operator = operations.pop(0)
        precedence = precedences[operator]
        while operators and precedences[operators[-1]] >= precedence:
            [left, right], stack[-2:] = stack[-2:], []
            stack.append(do[operators.pop()](left, right))
        operators.append(operator)
        stack.append(numbers.pop(0))
    while len(stack) > 1:
        [left, right], stack[-2:] = stack[-2:], []
        stack.append(do[operators.pop()](left, right))
    return stack[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Order of operations makes this hard but not impossible:

```py
# helper function to do an operation
def doop(num1, op, num2):
    if op == "^":
        return num1 ** num2
    if op == "+":
        return num1 + num2
    if op == "-":
        return num1 - num2
    if op == "*":
        return num1 * num2
    if op == "/":
        return num1 / num2
    # if we don't recognize the operation then error
    raise Exception("Invalid operation.")

# have a list of sets with operator precedence
precedence = [
    {"^"},
    {"*", "/"},
    {"+", "-"}
]

# hard coded values for testing
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
ops = ["+", "-", "*"]
# this represents 1 + 2 - 3 * 4

# start at highest to lowest precedence
for prec in precedence:
    # we have to use a while loop to have manual control of `i`
    i = 0
    while i < len(ops):
        # store the current operation
        op = ops[i]
        # if the operation isn't in the current precedence level we skip it
        if op in prec:
            # we can get rid of the operation to evaluate it
            ops.pop(i)
            # we can merge the two numbers around the operation into one
            # by performing the calculation
            nums[i:i + 2] = [doop(nums[i], op, nums[i + 1])]
            # we need to decrease i so we don't skip over the next operation
            i -= 1
        i += 1

if len(nums) != 1:
    raise Exception("Invalid operation count.")

print(nums[0]) # -9
```

Comment: aplet where's the explanation

Comment: I think a more specialized exception would work better, e.g. `ArithmeticError`.

Answer (score 1):

When performing a common processes on multiple values, you should use lists instead of individual variables.  This allows you to apply generic logic to elements and manipulate them based on indexes that you can store in variables:

```
def compute(*operNums):
    operNums   = list(operNums)
    numbers    = operNums[::2]  # [number0,number1,number2,number3]
    operations = operNums[1::2] # [operation0,operation1,operation2]
    while operations:           # process list until all operations performed
        for op in ("^","**","*","+"):          # find highest priority operation
            if op not in operations: continue
            i = operations.index(op)           # index of operation
            operations.pop(i)                  # remove completed operation
            if   op in ["^","**"]: numbers[i] **= numbers.pop(i+1) # remove right side
            elif op == "*":        numbers[i]  *= numbers.pop(i+1) # left side number
            elif op == "+":        numbers[i]  += numbers.pop(i+1) # is replaced by result   
            else: return "ERROR"
    return numbers[0]

print(compute(1,"+",2,"**",3,"*",5)) # 41
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use the operator library and try something like

```
from operator import pow, truediv, mul, add, sub  

operators = {
  '+': add,
  '-': sub,
  '*': mul,
  '/': truediv
}

def calculate(s):
    if s.isdigit():
        return float(s)
    for c in operators.keys():
        left, operator, right = s.partition(c)
        if operator in operators:
            return operators[operator](calculate(left), calculate(right))

calc = input("Type calculation:\n")
print("Answer: " + str(calculate(calc)))
```

Some other solutions are also available at https://levelup.gitconnected.com/3-ways-to-write-a-calculator-in-python-61642f2e4a9a

Comment: like karl's answer, doesn't handle precedence